# Less abstract AbstractExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I occasionally find myself needing to run code on some arbitrary thread or pass a Runnable to some arbitrary consumer, and missing the full functionality of java.util.concurrent -- for instance, writing Swing and JavaFX applications,  posting UI updates from a background thread to the main UI thread with [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) or [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

It's easy enough to wrap APIs like these in an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

```
class AppThreadExecutor implements Executor {
  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
      command.run();
    } else {
      Platform.runLater(command);
    }
  }
}
```

However, that doesn't really get you much; in particular, it doesn't get you `Futures`, or any interaction with helpful APIs like those in [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) or [Vavr](https://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.1.0-alpha/javaslang/concurrent/package-summary.html).

[AbstractExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) provides some but not all of the methods needed to bootstrap a single-abstract-method [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to a full [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Specifically, it's missing `shutdown()`, `shutdownNow()`, `isShutdown()`, `isTerminated()`, and `awaitTermination()`.

I could write my own implementation ([and have](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163003/delegating-executorservice-implementation-requiring-only-an-executor)), but I'd prefer an existing, well-tested library class (or even a choice of them with different performance characteristics or shutdown guarantees). Does anything like that exist?

---

**N.b.** This isn't really a question about Swing or JavaFX; those are just examples of the kind of situation that might require bootstrapping from an arbitrary thread or an Executor-like task runner to a full ExecutorService. If you have specific advice about how this is the wrong approach for those frameworks, I appreciate that, but please make it a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is JavaFX you can give a try to JRebirth Application Framework that provides a real abstraction over threading and memory concerns.

No need to manipulate future, every async tasks are handled using internal event bus (sending and handling internal message).
Behind the scene it uses 2 Thread pools to execute runnable, but also allows to run tasks into graphical thread or internal messaging thread.

The more easy to learn this approach is to read source code:

- https://github.com/JRebirth/ComparisonTool
- https://github.com/JRebirth/MasteringTables

Some links to documentation:

- http://jrebirth.org/doc/Overview.html
- http://jrebirth.org/doc/Thread.html
- http://jrebirth.org/doc/Facades.html